# How to extract as large a number as possible by random sample?

Tags: list-manipulation, distributions

When I extract a element from a list by random sample, I want to extract as large a number as possible
(It mean it's not always extracted the max value.)

For example, when I take a element by random sample from

```
listA={1,3,5,3,7,20}
```

the number is clearly 20

However, when the variation in the list is not widely(small standard deviation) like bellow

```
listB={11,12,13,12,10,9}
```

I hope that the number is 13, but could output 12 or 11.

I don't think it follows a normal distribution in the case of a list with a lot of variation.

When there is littele variation, RandoSample from normal distribution may be all that is needed. But I don't think Random Sample from  normal distribution is the way to go when taking out larger elements from biased lists.

I will have a large number of lists to process and the elements of the lists are varied, I would like to extract the larger some in the same function.

Do you have any suggestions?
I am not very good at English, so I'm not sure whether I can tell clearly.

Comment: The question is unclear. A uniform random sample always has a potential to pull the maximal element from the list, and the number value of any non-maximal element in the list has no impact on that likelihood. What kind of principle are you imagining which makes sampling `listA` certainly 20 and `listB` possibly 11, 12, or 13?

Comment: Consider: `listA = {1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 20};
FindAnomalies[listA]`.  Now you can find anomalies in `listB`.

Answer (score 3):

> ... extract as large a number as "possible"

**Using `Nearest`:**

The `nearOrMax` function chooses from as many neighbors near the maximum as specified.

```
nearOrMax[k_List, neighbors_Integer] := Module[{nf},
  nf = Nearest[k];
  RandomChoice[nf[Max[k], neighbors]]
  ]

SeedRandom[1];
listB = {11, 12, 13, 12, 10, 9};
Table[nearOrMax[listB, 4], 10]
```

{11, 12, 13, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 12, 11}

With a choice `5` neighbors near the maximum:

```
SeedRandom[2];
Table[nearOrMax[listB, 5], 10]
```

{12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 10, 11, 10}

Comment: For large lists, make `nf` global to avoid this computation repeatedly. There will be no reason to create a function then.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps finding the max of a noisy list could give you something like what you're describing here. Starting with the lists given:

```
listA = {1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 20};
listB = {11, 12, 13, 12, 10, 9};
```

Let's define a function which finds the maximal element while adding random noise sampled from a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation `s`:

```
noisyMax[l_, s_] := 
  First@l[[Ordering[
             l + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, s], Length[l]],
             -1]
         ]];
```

This adds noise to the list `l`, finds the position of the largest element, and returns it without the noise.

For `s == 1`, for `listA` it almost always returns 20. Out of 10000 samples on my machine, all 10000 returned 20.

```
datA = Table[noisyMax[listA, 1], {10000}];
Tally[datA]
```

> {{20, 10000}}

But for `listB`, significant overlap is seen, with even 10 and 9 very rarely being chosen over 13. For one run, for example:

```
datB = Table[noisyMax[listB, 1], {10000}];
SortBy[Tally[datB], -#[[1]] &] (* sorting it this time for clarity *)
```

> {{13, 6139}, {12, 3494}, {11, 335}, {10, 30}, {9, 2}}

Thus, 13 about 61% of the time, 12 about 35% of the time, 11 about 3% of the time, 10 about 0.3% of the time, and 9 about 0.02% of the time.

Note that this is much more computationally intensive than just finding the maximum. If performance is the goal and the maximum is close enough to "usually the maximum", then use `Max`.

Comment: Your answer may be what I was looking for. I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, where did listl come from?

Comment: @hare: `l` is just a name for any list passed into the `noisyMax` function, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

listA = {1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 20};

listB = {11, 12, 13, 12, 10, 9};
```

It is not clear what you want. If you just want to bias a random selection, then limit the selection to values greater than or equal to the `Mean` or the `Median` or whatever.

```
rand[list_List, f_ : Mean] := RandomChoice[Select[list, # >= f[list] &]]

SeedRandom[1234];
```

For `listA`

```
N[#[listA]] & /@ {Mean, Median}

(* {6.5, 4.} *)

Table[rand[listA], 20]

(* {20, 20, 20, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 20, 20, 7, 20, 7, 7, 20, 7, 20, 20, 7} *)

% // Mean // N

(* 12.85 *)

Table[rand[listA, Median], 20]

(* {20, 20, 5, 5, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 20, 5, 7, 5, 7, 5, 20, 5, 7, 7, 20} *)

% // Mean // N

(* 9.25 *)
```

For `listB`

```
N[#[listB]] & /@ {Mean, Median}

(* {11.1667, 11.5} *)

Table[rand[listB], 20]

(* {13, 13, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 12, 12, 13, 13, 12, 12, 13, 12, 12, 13, 13, 12, 12} *)

% // Mean // N

(* 12.4 *)

Table[rand[listB, Median], 20]

(* {13, 12, 12, 12, 13, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 12, 13, 12, 12, 12, 12} *)

% // Mean // N

(* 12.2 *)
```